# error in data extraction using rawQuery

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am trying to extract contacts from a database. In the code below, when invoking the `rawQuery()`, I get error saying that object cast needs to be done when `db` is an object. I am confused about the parameters `rawQuery()` takes. Please can you explain it to me?

```
String select = "SELECT id, name FROM contacts WHERE email = " + email;
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(select, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String select = "SELECT id, name FROM contacts WHERE email = " + email;
```

In your case this code won't work because you are directly adding parameters to query that requires wrap them into single quotes (otherwise it won't work and SQLite will interpret value as column and Exception will be thrown). So you need to change it to:

```
String select = "SELECT id, name FROM contacts WHERE email = '" + email + "'";
```

and it should works now.

---

But I don't like your approach. It's not very human readable and dangerous (SQL injection). I strongly recommend you to use parametrized queries which are faster, safer and more human readable.

**Example:**

```
String select = "SELECT id, name FROM contacts WHERE email = ?";
String[] whereArgs = {email};
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(select, whereArgs);
```

Hope it helps.

**Note:** Also make sure you have correctly initialised SQLiteDatabase instance.

Comment: I used the second approach.Thank you for the suggestion. Still an error is displayed in rawQuery and it says create method rawQuery in DBAdapter. Can you explain it to me? I am new to android and this is rather confusing!!!

Comment: @user2761022 [rawQuery()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) is method SQLiteDatabase instance and not of your custom implemented DBAdapter. So you need to call rawQuery on your SQLiteDatabase instance.

Comment: db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
 I have done in  DBAdapter. and in the activity i have instantiated it as DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this); Still, why is the error message?

Comment: you cannot use `DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);` Your adapter has not rawQuery() method! your db variable must be instance of SQLiteDatabase and not DBAdapter.

Comment: Ahhh...thanks!!! Finally, it is done. Thank you for explaining it to me patiently!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Cursor  cursor = dh.rawQuery("SELECT _id ,name  FROM contacts WHERE email LIKE ? ", new String[] {"%"});
```